# how do i delete apps from the Launcher on Mac Monterey?

Tags: monterey, launchpad

Clicking on the icon until it wiggles does not allow me to drag it to the Trash.

Answer (score 4):

> 3. Press and hold the Option (⌥) key, or click and hold any app until the apps start jiggling.
> 4. Click the Delete button next to the app you want to remove, then click Delete to confirm. The app will be deleted immediately. Apps that don't have a Delete button either didn't come from the App Store or are required by your Mac. To delete an app that didn't come from the App Store, use the Finder instead.

https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202235

Comment: Works for some apps - thanks.  Others apparently can't be deleted, e.g., Bootcamp.